# How to link to different controllers in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a `ListCtrl`, responsible for fetching data from server and paginating it (it will work for ALL my resources). However, It must receive a few `configurations` prior to setup the Path to the resource, default limit, and so on...

The way I thought doing it, is to use my ListCtrl inside a bigger Controller, but initialising it with a few params like this:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as dashboard">
 <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as list" ng-init="list.init(dashboard.listParams)">
  <... Iterate through list.items ...>
 </div>
</div>
```

Reading a few articles, I saw that using `ng-init` is not good, and should be used only for lists initialisation. Is there a better approach, without using `ng-init`? Or is this just ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead of just attaching a controller directly to a DOM element. A directive allows you to explicitly handle passing data between controllers without relying on global state (which many solutions using services effectively rely upon).

You would want to create a directive that accepts some sort of configuration, which you could then pass via an attribute.

```
angular.module('yourApp').directive('yourList', function () {
  return {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'ListCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'list',
    scope: {
      params: '='
    }
  };
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as dashboard">
  <your-list params="dashboard.listParams"></your-list>
</div>
```

The `params` property will then be available on `ListCtrl`'s scope. To handle the template used by your directive, you could use a separate partial, or you could use [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to keep the elements in your main template.

Comment: Hi Alexis, this idea is what I was looking for! However, it seems that my scope params are not getting to the Directive's controller. I tried with many names, but no success. Any idea?

Comment: @IvanSeidel It's hard for me to diagnose your problem without a code example. Could you either link me to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or post a separate question?

Comment: Found out what it is. the `scope` bindings are passed to te controller's scope, not the $scope... using `this.myVar` instead of  `$scope.myVar`.

Comment: @IvanSeidel Yes, this is what `bindToController` and `controllerAs` do. You can remove those options and use `$scope`, but I used `controllerAs` in my example since you were using the `as` syntax in your question.

Comment: That's better I think. I Don't like binding it to `$scope`, as it is more code behind it for nothing (in my case)...

Comment: @IvanSeidel Yes, using the `controllerAs` syntax is generally recommended over using `$scope` directly.

Comment: One more thing: It seems that setting stuff from inside my `ListCtrl` in `$scope.something` doesn't affects my views. Why is that? Or it should work..

Comment: @IvanSeidel If you're using the `controllerAs` syntax, setting values on `$scope` will no longer work, you'll need to use `this` everywhere instead. (However, a Stack Overflow comment thread isn't a good place to have this discussion. If you have a separate question, please ask it as a separate question.)